# Arrays: Consolidate sparse array into one which is more densely populated

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below table which is sparsely populated but also has duplicates down the columns.

```
+------------+---------+
| LX ID      | ISIN    |
+------------+---------+
| A          | X       |
| B          | Y       |
|            | Z       |
| B          |         |
|            | X       |
| A          |         |
| B          | Y       |
| A          | X       |
+------------+---------+
```

Using `df[["LX ID", "ISIN"]].drop_duplicates()` produces the below which gets rid of identical rows but still has duplicates down the columns (for instance the last 3 columns):

```
+------------+---------+
| LX ID      | ISIN    |
+------------+---------+
| A          | X       |
| B          | Y       |
|            | Z       |
| B          |         |
|            | X       |
| A          |         |
+------------+---------+
```

What solution would you propose where it discards rows where there is already a row which is more complete (e.g. discarding the last row as the first row is better filled out)? An example of the final condensed table is below:

```
+------------+---------+
| LX ID      | ISIN    |
+------------+---------+
| A          | X       |
| B          | Y       |
|            | Z       |
+------------+---------+
```

Thanks,

Kieran

Comment: It's not clear what is "more densely populated". Also, it'd be nice if you provide your attempt to solve the problem and show its output.

Comment: Thanks yeputons. I have edited the question to better illustrate the objective.

Comment: df.groupby(['LX ID'])['IS IN'].nunique().reset_index()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using an outer join, with two flavours.. The inputs have been tweaked slightly to demonstrate that rows with two values are favoured ahead of rows with one value.

First, set up:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: 
   ...: ids = pd.DataFrame(
   ...:     index=['LX ID', 'ISIN'],
   ...:     data=[['A', 'B', '', 'B', '', 'A', 'B', 'A'], 
   ...:           ['', 'Y', 'Z', '', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'X']], 
   ...: ).T
   ...: ids


Out[1]: 
  LX ID ISIN
0     A     
1     B    Y
2          Z
3     B     
4          X
5     A    X
6     B    Y
7     A    X
```

Then sort by 'fullness':

```
In [2]: ids['full'] = (ids['LX ID'] != '') & (ids['ISIN'] != '')
   ...: ids.sort_values('full', ascending=False, inplace=True)
   ...: ids

Out[2]: 
  LX ID ISIN   full
1     B    Y   True
5     A    X   True
6     B    Y   True
7     A    X   True
0     A       False
2          Z  False
3     B       False
4          X  False
```

Then split the two series, discard blanks and drop duplicates (by default keeping first occurrence):

```
lx = ids['LX ID']
isin = ids['ISIN']
lx = lx[lx != ''].drop_duplicates()
isin = isin[isin != ''].drop_duplicates()
```

Then use an outer join in one of the two ways, replacing NaNs with empty strings.. The correct rows are joined back together because the implicit index from the first data frame when separating the two series is preserved.

Explicit join:

```
In [3]: pd.DataFrame(lx).join(isin, how='outer').fillna('')

Out[3]: 
  LX ID ISIN
1     B    Y
2          Z
5     A    X
```

Or via constructor:

```
In [4]: pd.DataFrame([lx, isin]).T.fillna('')

Out[4]: 
  LX ID ISIN
1     B    Y
2          Z
5     A    X
```

---

The whole thing can be simplified if we have NaNs rather than blanks (which may be what you get by default anyway if reading from xls/ csv?):

```
In [5]: import pandas as pd
   ...: _ = pd.np.nan
   ...: ids = pd.DataFrame(
   ...:     index=['LX ID', 'ISIN'],
   ...:     data=[['A', _, 'B', _, 'B', _, 'A', 'B', 'A'], 
   ...:           [_, _, 'Y', 'Z', _, 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'X']], 
   ...: ).T
   ...: ids


Out[5]: 
  LX ID ISIN
0     A  NaN
1   NaN  NaN
2     B    Y
3   NaN    Z
4     B  NaN
5   NaN    X
6     A    X
7     B    Y
8     A    X
```

The count function, applied to rows, counts non-NaN values, which we then use to sort:

```
In [6]: ids['order'] = ids.count(axis=1)
   ...: ids.sort_values('order', ascending=False, inplace=True)

Out[6]: 
  LX ID ISIN  order
2     B    Y      2
6     A    X      2
7     B    Y      2
8     A    X      2
0     A  NaN      1
3   NaN    Z      1
4     B  NaN      1
5   NaN    X      1
1   NaN  NaN      0
```

Then similar to before, but using dropna() rather than explicit empty string comparison:

```
In [7]: lx = ids['LX ID'].dropna().drop_duplicates()
    ...: isin = ids['ISIN'].dropna().drop_duplicates()
    ...: pd.DataFrame(lx).join(isin, how='outer')

Out[7]: 
  LX ID ISIN
2     B    Y
3   NaN    Z
6     A    X
```